# Using cut or sed in Android busybox

Tags: android, adb, cut, busybox

I want to trim a string in adb.
If I write busybox --help it lists cut and sed as available commands.

```
mount |grep -e /system
```

works, but

```
 mount |grep -e /system| cut -f 1 -d ' '
```

doesn't work. Is there a special Syntax in android's busybox?
I also tried

```
 echo "Hello World"|cut -f 1 -d ' '
```

from the manpage and it doesn't work..

```
root@android:/ # busybox cut --help
busybox cut --help
BusyBox v1.21.1-Stericson (2013-07-08 15:58:11 BST) multi-call binary.

Usage: cut [OPTIONS] [FILE]...

Print selected fields from each input FILE to stdout

    -b LIST Output only bytes from LIST
    -c LIST Output only characters from LIST
    -d CHAR Use CHAR instead of tab as the field delimiter
    -s      Output only the lines containing delimiter
    -f N    Print only these fields
    -n      Ignored
```

Comment: 1st check the available option `cut --help`

Comment: added available options to the question.

Comment: Just added busybox to the line and it works. It's the same as

    `cut --help`

doesn't work, but

    `busybox cut --help`
does.

    `mount |grep -e /system|busybox cut -f 1 -d ' '`

Comment: Maybe there's no symlink from `cut` to busybox, or maybe some even more primitive version is first in your search path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `busybox` applets to work the way you expect you need to create the appropriate symlinks first:

```
$ adb shell whence sed
$ adb shell sed
/system/bin/sh: sed: not found
$ adb root
$ adb remount
remount succeeded
$ adb shell whence busybox
/system/bin/busybox
$ adb shell ln -s /system/bin/busybox /system/bin/sed
$ adb shell whence sed
/system/bin/sed
$ adb shell sed
Usage: sed [-efinr] SED_CMD [FILE]...
```

Or just do `mount | grep -e /system | busybox cut -f 1 -d ' '`

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my Comment it works, the error was indeed the lack of symlinks. I didn't realize as there was no error when I typed "sed" or "cut", it found the command and gave me the list of arguments. Still I had to use the busybox command and not the alias. Thank you for your help!